# Django - Staging choices in ModelForm - a better way?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've set up options for my `ChoiceField` when the form is initialized like so:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        buid_choices = [(v.id,v.buid) for v in Vendor.objects.exclude(buid='').order_by('buid')]
        self.fields['vendors'].choices = buid_choices
```

The above code works fine for populating the form with choices, but there are duplicate `buid`'s in the returned queryset for `Vendor` nor can I additionally filter the queryset to give me only unique values for the buid (unless there's a queryset method I'm not aware of). I am using sqlite3 backend, so using `.distinct()` is out.

**Can anyone suggest a better way to do the following without multiple hits to the database?**

```
vendors = Vendor.objects.exclude(buid='').order_by('buid')
buid_list, buid_choices = [],[]
for v in vendors:
    if v.buid not in buid_list:
        buid_list.append(v.buid)
        buid_choices.append((v.id,v.buid))
```

This will give me what I want...no duplicates for buid, but it kind of makes my skin crawl to conditionally add items to two lists while checking for membership in the first one. Seems like there should be a better more pythonic way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Is it so bad to hit the DB multiple times if you are avoiding it at the expense of doing the same work in Python? You could do `Vendor.objects.exclude(buid='').values_list("buid", flat=True).distinct()` and then use those buids to filter again on Vendor.

Comment: Hmmm...strange. I just plugged in your code into the shell with and without the `distinct()`. Without, it gave me what one would expect, with it, however, only eliminated some of the duplicates. Don't really have time at the moment to delve deeper, but I'm curious about this behavior...

Comment: That's odd, because it's just one column (buid), but you could always use a python set to get the unique values.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Appears I will be be sticking with the status quo for the time being. I had considered using a set to get the unique values, but then I'd have to somehow pull in the `id` for my choices, as all `id`'s and `buid`'s are unique together.